# mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting (with NFSv4)

Tags: mount, permissions, nfs

I'm running two VMs (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) as NFSv4 server and client:

```
nfs4server 172.28.128.3
nfs4client 10.0.2.16
```

On nfs4server, I have `nfs-kernel-server` and `nfs-common` installed. The mount point is:

```
vagrant@nfs4server:~$ cat /etc/exports
/shares/wordpress 10.0.0.0/8(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

On nfs4client, I have `nfs-utils`, `rpcbind`, and `nfs-common` installed. I can see the server's mount points available:

```
vagrant@nfs4client:~$ showmount -e 172.28.128.3
Export list for 172.28.128.3:
/shares/wordpress 10.0.0.0/8
```

My client mount directory's user/group is the same as the server mount directory's user/group.

```
vagrant@nfs4server:~$ ls -l /shares
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 anyperk www-data 4096 Nov 24 10:52 wordpress

vagrant@nfs4client:~$ ls -l /mnt/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 anyperk www-data 4096 Nov 24 10:36 wordpress_shared_content
```

However, when I attempt to mount the directory, I get the following error:

```
vagrant@nfs4client:~$ sudo mount -v -t nfs 172.28.128.3:/shares/wordpress /mnt/wordpress_shared_content/
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Nov 24 10:59:02 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=172.28.128.3,clientaddr=10.0.2.15'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 172.28.128.3:/shares/wordpress
```

I assume it's a permissions issue but I've tried multiple permissions-related fixes to no avail:

- set network access for `/shares/wordpress` to "*" instead of
  "10.0.0.0/8" - **did not work**
- added "fsid=0" option to
  `/etc/exports`, run `exportfs -a` and re-attempt to mount - **did not
  work**
- explicitly set "uid=anyperk","gid=www-data" options in
  `/etc/exports` to match the mount directory permissions, run
  `exportfs -a` and re-attempt to mount - **did not work**

Answer (score 0):

Due to Vagrant's networking, the two VMs could not properly communicate/authenticate on different networks. I moved both VMs onto the same DHCP network (172.28.128.0/24) and the client was able to mount the share without any problems.